# BEGINNER: Python--How to embed elif statements into a while loop (that changes the route of output each time through the loop?!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

##Here's an example of what I've been working on:
##so far I've used num set to zero and num set to the full num=int(input statement... I've learned both ways so far and I'm not sure if I need to use it at all, but when I do it's usually for when I have a for statement asking to keep track of for x in range (0, inp+1): which I've already tried to no avail...

##okay, so here's what I've been trying to do for THREE days now... and it will drive me crazy till I get this! I'm trying to get the program to give output while true (that num is not equal to 11; if not equal to 11, print "nope"; if nope isn't printed, it's supposed to go on to the next statement, etc., etc., until it hits 11. But here's the thing. It's SUPPOSED to try the first statement while true, and change each time through the loop! I have a bunch of other ways I've tried this while racking my brain over it and haven't gotten it QUITE right yet so here's the basic nitty-gritty:

````
num=0

while num != 11:
    num=int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 20 (17 to stop): "))
    print(num)
    if num != 11:
        print("nope")
    elif num >=3:
        print("history")
    elif num < 20:
        print("bye")
    elif num > 12:
        print("cat")
    elif num >= 7:
        print("push")
    else:
        print("sat")```
````

Comment: Could you maybe give an example of how you envision this working?  What if they enter, say, 10, 1, and then 5?  Does it say "nope", "bye", "history", or does it say "nope", "bye", "sat", or does it just say "nope", "nope", "nope" (which is how it's written now)?

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a list of conditions that you run through on each input, popping them off as they're met, but it's not clear to me exactly what the rules are for what happens when the next condition isn't met.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because any number that isn't 11 will be caught in the if, then the loop starts again. If you type 11 the loop just prints history then exits. Doing this will first check if it's not 11, then check the other conditions. It's a bit unclear what you want to happen. And 11 is stopping not 17. But hopefully this helps a bit.

```
num=0
while num != 11:
    num=int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 20 (17 to stop): "))
    print(num)
    if num != 11:
        print("nope")
    if num >=3:
        print("history")
    elif num < 20:
        print("bye")
    elif num > 12:
        print("cat")
    elif num >= 7:
        print("push")
    else:
        print("sat")
```

Comment: I'm so sorry it's confusing for me as well. What I'm learning in a book compared to a "program" vs. actual python are so different and it's driving me crazy! I want to learn this so badly but it's so all over the place I'm not sure which to follow.

Comment: If you edit your question and show exactly what you want the output to be for each number that you input then this can be refined based on those rules. Without that it's hard to tell.

Comment: I want to learn this so badly but it's so all over the place I'm not sure which to follow. So basically, if I enter 8, it's supposed to tell me "nope"; next if I enter 19, it's supposed to just show me the printed input "19"; then if I want to enter 11, it's supposed to just put "11" as the output rather than any of the words. Once it's finished with the loop it starts all over again; in the second round it's like entering "3" and I'm somehow supposed to get "nope"!!? Like WHAT?!?! Sorry, not your fault but I'm completely lost on how that's supposed to work...

Comment: The best thing I would suggest is to edit what youo've said here into your question. Use bullet points to clearly show each input and output.

Answer (score 0):

> if I enter 8, it's supposed to tell me "nope"; next if I enter 19, it's supposed to just show me the printed input "19"; then if I want to enter 11, it's supposed to just put "11" as the output rather than any of the words. Once it's finished with the loop it starts all over again; in the second round it's like entering "3" and I'm somehow supposed to get "nope"

It sounds like you just want something like:

```
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 20 (17 to stop): "))
    print(num)
    if num == 11:
        continue
    print("nope")
    while num != 11:
        num = int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 20 (17 to stop): "))
        print(num)
```

From your description it doesn't sound like you're ever supposed to see any of the other words so all of that code is unnecessary.